Open mapping Theorem and topology
The Open Mapping Theorem in complex analysis states that, if $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb C$ is a region and $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb C$ is an non-constant holomorphic map, then $f$ is an open map. Now, my question is: concerning which topology on $\Omega$?
Naturally, the topology on $\mathbb C$ is the standard (euclidean) one, but when it come to $\Omega$, do we have the standard topology of $\mathbb C$ or the induced topology from $\mathbb C$?

Usually "region" implies that the set is open, and in such case the induced topology agrees with the global one.
The definition of derivative at a point (in which we base the definition of holomorphic) requires that a ball around the point is in the domain of the function, for otherwise some Newton quotients make no sense.

Okay fair enough, so to be ever "over-"clear: $\Omega$ is here a region in the standard topology of $\mathbb C$, right?

What other topology would it possibly be? You use the standard topology in the definition of derivative.

Yes you're right, I just allowed in my mind some unnecessary construction: since a region is a not-empty, connected and open set in a topological space, I was thinking about whether we were allowing $\Omega$ to be any non-empty connected subset of $\mathbb C$ and use the induced topology form $\mathbb C$ on $\Omega$, this way the latter would have been " a region" in its own topology. As you correctly pointed out though, the whole should be read as $\Omega$ is a region (relative to the standard topology on $\mathbb C$) in $\mathbb C$.
